# How to assign a SendGrid category with Contact Form 7 and WP Mail SMTP

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid, contact-form-7

I'm trying to assign a SendGrid category on the emails sent by a form.

SendGrid documentation mentions the use of `X-SMTPAPI`, it says it should contain a json object in there, and adding `{'category': 'cat1'}` is supposed to do the trick.

[image: Contact Form]

This is what I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

As WP Mail SMTP uses the v3 API to send mail, you need to add your custom categories to the request body.

You can do this with the following piece of code:

```
function wp_mail_smtp_add_cat( $body, $mailer ) {
    $body['categories'] = array('testcat');
    return $body;
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_smtp_providers_mailer_get_body', 'wp_mail_smtp_add_cat', 10, 2 );
```

For other parameters, check the v3 documentation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful!